# search center filter by content type

Tags: 2010, search

In the current site we have a search center, but we would need to customize it to be able to filter by content type before the user types the search.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with Advanced Search. You can follow the guide at http://waelmohamed.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/add-custom-search-properties-in-your-advanced-search-sharepoint-2010/ where it does exactly what you need. On step 6, when you add the mapping to the crawled property, just select "ows_ContentType" instead of "ReferenceNo" that the guide uses.

Comment: I really need step by step instructions. thx